# An error with displaying multi-level menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying a multi-level menu in mvc4.
When I run the code, **main children of my menu and also their main children are displayed correctly**
but **at third level, the following menus display over each other**
what should I do?

here is my code:

```html
@helper getmenutree(int? parentId)
{
    
    foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.ParentId == parentId))
    { 
    <li>

        <a href="#">@item.Name</a>
        <ul>
            @if (item.Groups1.Any())
            {
                @getmenutree(item.Id)
                        
            }
        </ul>
    </li>

    }
   
}


<nav id="main_nav">
   <ul>
    
      @getmenutree(null)
       
   </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: your question is not so clear - can you provide: 1. what is the menu model look like, 2. what is it producing when you say over each other?, 3. what do you expect

Comment: I want to create a horizontal malti-level-menu.
for example my menu items are A and B and C.
A has two submenus like A1 and A2. A1 has  2 submenus like A11 and A12.
when I run the code, A and B,C displayed and when I hover over  A, A1 and A2 display under it correctly.
 but when I hover over A1, its children(A11,A12) display on A1 and A2. 
I want submenus are displayed next to the corresponding menu rather than the previous submenu
I hope my description is clearly

Comment: I think your problem is to do with css not razor, as your code is generating more or less correct hierarchy (see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAEf47).  So my hunch is that your menu css does not support multi level sub menu